Improving Ellipsoid Theorem $t+\mathcal{E} \subseteq K \subset t + c\cdot n \mathcal{E}$
Setting:
Definition (ellipsoid): An ellipsoid is $\mathcal{E} := \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||A^{-1}(y-t)|| \leq 1\}$, i.e images under a given $A$ of full rank of the unit closed ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Definition (convex body): A convex body is a convex compact, with nonempty interior part subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Definition (centrally symmetric): $K$ is centrally symmetric if when $x \in K$ then $-x \in K$
I have a proof of the following Theorem:
Theorem: For all convex body $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ exists $\mathcal{E}$ centered in $0$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $t+\mathcal{E} \subseteq K \subset t + c\cdot n \mathcal{E}$.
where $c$ is a constant independent from $n$, $c > 130$.
Goal: What I'd like to construct is a proof for Theorem: For all centrally symmetric convex body $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ exists $\mathcal{E}$ centered in $0$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $t+\mathcal{E} \subseteq K \subset t + c\cdot \sqrt{n} \mathcal{E}$.
Outline of the proof:
I want to modify the proof of the previous theorem, essentially the idea of the proof is to argue by contradiction, wlog using the unit ball. So we find a point $z \in K$ with norm $cn$ by convexity of $K$, which, up to rotation can be brought onto the $e_1$ direction. Now the idea is to look at the convex hull of $B(0,1) \cup \{cn e_1\}$ and argument to find an ellipsoid inside $K$ with volume greater of the unit ball $V_n$, ending the proof.
The proof is constructive i.e $$\mathcal{E'} := x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\alpha^2_i}(x_i-t_i)^2 \leq 1$$, where $t = e_1, \alpha_1 = 2,\alpha_i = \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+(1/10)}}$ for $i\geq 2$.
In particular $vol(\mathcal{E'}) > V_n$ if and only if $2\cdot(\frac{n}{n+\frac{1}{10}})^{\frac{n-1}{2}} > 1$ which is (incredibly) true because of $$ 2\cdot(\frac{n}{n+\frac{1}{10}})^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \geq 2\cdot(\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{10n}}})^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\geq 2\cdot(\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{10n}}}) \geq 2\cdot(\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{20}}}) > 1$$
This is important since if we show that $\mathcal{E'} \subset$ convex hull of $B(0,1) \cup \{cn e_1\}$ we are done. In order to do this, we parametrize the line segment between $cn \cdot e_1$ and a vector $y$ such that $||y|| = 1$ with $y_1 = 0$, up to rotations we can take $e_2$ and show that for the points of the line segment $x_{\lambda} = \lambda e_2 + (1-\lambda)cn e_1$ it holds that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\alpha^2_i}(x_{\lambda}-t)_i^2 > 1$$ for $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
This is true because if $\lambda \geq 1 - \frac{1}{30n}$ then $(1+\frac{1}{10n})(1-\frac{1}{30n})^2 > 1$. While for $0 \leq \lambda < 1 - \frac{1}{30n}$ then $\frac{1}{4}((1-\lambda)cn - 1)^2 \geq \frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{30n}cn-1)^2 > 1$ for $c$ large enough $\Box$.
At this point, I thought take replacing $\alpha_i$ by putting simply $\sqrt{n}$ would have worked (hear the "ice cream" convex hull has two cones so that we can replace t=0, centering it in the origin), and indeed it does with different inequalities and constants if it wasn't that in showing $vol(\mathcal{E'}) > V_n$ I made a mistake not realizing that the basis of the exponential is smaller than $1$.
I know this theorem holds with $C =1$, for example, a reference can be found in "A course in Convexity" by Barvinok, but I think the proof is unnecessarily complicated since here we don't require that $C=1$. Do you have an idea how to adjust the argument? Any help would be appreciated.

Should we assume $A$ is a linear operator of full rank? Also, what is meant by "Centrally symmetric"?

@Zim yes thanks, I’ve added hypothesis and definition.

I'm not sure I understand the question. Both theorems hold with $C = 1$, as in Barvinok's book (and the second theorem also with $t = 0$). Do you want to get a simpler proof at the cost of a larger constant $C$? If so, I don't see how your sketch can be made to work, since nowhere you seem to be using that $K$ is centrally symmetric. I don't know about simpler, but there is a more formal proof that you may like (it doesn't require pictures and proves a more general statement). You can find it in Chapter 3 of Pisier's The Volume of Convex Bodies and Banach Space Geometry.
